# How to fix 'filter_' error in a function I have created?

Tags: r

I routinely get datasets from a database where test profiles are created with the last name "Bogus"
I decided to write a function to extract out the rows that contain these test cases (Bogus cases)

Following is an example of the type of data I receive. Lets call this Data frame `names`

```
FirstName<-c("Alan","James","Miles","Nath")
LastName<-c("Bottom","Bogus","Davis","Gun")

names<-data.frame(FirstName,LastName)  

  FirstName LastName
      Alan   Bottom
     James    Bogus
     Miles    Davis
      Nath      Gun
```

I created a function called `bogusfun`as follows

```
bogusfun<-function(df){
  if(any(grepl("Bogus",df))) # This is to see which column contains  "Bogus" profiles
  col<-(colnames(df[grepl("Bogus",df)])) # This line assigns the column name containing the Bogus profile
  col<-as.name(col)  
  library(dplyr)
  df<-df%>%
    filter(col!="Bogus")
  return(df)
}
```

When I run this function on a dataframe

`bogusfun(names)`

I would expect to see

```
  FirstName LastName
     Alan   Bottom
     Miles    Davis
     Nath      Gun
```

However it doesn't work as expected. So I looked at the following section of the code

```
if(any(grepl("Bogus",names)))
  col<-colnames(names[grepl("Bogus",names)])
  col<-as.name(col)
  df<-df%>%
      filter(col="Bogus")
```

and it gives me the error Error in `UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can use `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
names %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(. != 'Bogus'))
#  FirstName LastName
#1      Alan   Bottom
#2     Miles    Davis
#3      Nath      Gun
```

---

Or with `filter/across`

```
names %>%
   filter(across(everything(), ~ . != 'Bogus'))
#  FirstName LastName
#1      Alan   Bottom
#2     Miles    Davis
#3      Nath      Gun
```

---

In the OP's function, `grep` is applied don the entire dataset whereas `grep` works on `vector/matrix`.  According to `?grep`

> x, text - a character vector where matches are sought, or an object which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector. Long vectors are supported.